Bloat on replcia (standby)
To detect bloat we run some heavy queries, but since they may affect the db server we do it before or after primetime.
Could we run these queries (basically, check bloat) on the physical replication standby server?
Since bloat is replicating too, it should work.. I don't have resources to test it and I couldn't find a word about it on the internet.

It should work fine. Right as you said, physical replica has same bloating as primary.

But, I remembered now, the most correct way to count bloat is to create extension pgstattuple. So I guess we should create it on primary, it will replicate on standby and the we can run out query (with pgstattuple data)?

*** Correct. ***
